# Have you ever experienced that "accept but needs final editing"

Tags: publications

I have submitted my article to springer journal. We re-arrenged the manuscript that was requested by reviewers. And we submitted again. 50 days later, the decision was "accept but needs final editing". Has any one experienced this status? Is still there any rejection risk? Thanks.

Comment: This status is very common. And, yes, it's still possible to get rejected at this point. For example, if the referees tell you to remove an *ad hominem* attack on another researcher, and you refuse, the manuscript will probably get rejected.

Comment: @PeterShor You should probably make your comment an answer.

Comment: You know that the status is "accept but needs final editing" but don't have any feedback yet ?

Comment: I submitted the edited version of my manuscript 3 days ago, and status changed as editor assigned again. I dont have feedback yet. I am so impatiant and worried for bad news.